# Image source from django variable

Tags: python, html, django, image, variables

I am looking for a way different possible image source in my html code, depending on result of a python function.

Exemple if:

```
state = isOnline()
```

is a function that can say if a device is online or not, it returns:

> True

then I would obtain

```
IMG_URL = imgSource(state)
```

would return the source for online image

> static 'project\img\true.jpg'

which I would then through my views.py used as:

```
def device(request):

    return render(request, 'device.html', {'IMG_URL': IMG_URL})
```

and then I could use this variable in my html code.

```
<img src="{% IMG_URL %}" alt="Post">
```

I hope you guys will be capable to help me, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
def device(request):
    # this could be generated in any number of ways, but this is a simple one
    IMG_URL = 'http://example.com/online_image.jpg' if is_online() else '/local/img/offline_image.jpg'

    return render(request, 'device.html', {'IMG_URL': IMG_URL})
```

There are some ideas for checking if you're online or not [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913411/test-if-an-internet-connection-is-present-in-python).

Comment: My question is more about how to pass an image source as a variable since with {{ IMG_URL }} it always get to be a string ?

And in case that I don't have only 2 possibilities a solution of this type could be very difficult probably no ?

Comment: No. An image source is always a string, and that's what I'd pass to the render function. I'd suggest you figure out what that source is as close to calling `render()` as possible like in my update.