# Find VirusTotal API IP address and port number?

Tags: python, api, nmap

I am currently working on a script that makes use of the VirusTotal API.

My question is different from the one that was marked as duplicate, because I would like to know in which port my request goes, and since I need to use a specific URL, I cannot use `nmap` (it only accepts domain names).

It involves a certain level of automation, so I would like to test if there is a connection between my computer and the endpoint before submitting something to check. For example, to get the latest report on a certain URL, I would use the `https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report` endpoint, with `requests.get()` method from the `requests` module.

Now I have come across an elegant solution for this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40283805/12143140.

I would need to know  which port number this request goes to, in order to perform the check as in the answer above. I think I would have to use something like `socket.create_connection(("virustotal.com", 587))`.

But I am not sure about the `587`. I found it using `nmap www.virustotal.com`, and among others it returned

```
PORT     STATE     SERVICE
587/tcp   open     submission
```

Then I tried `nmap virustotal.com -p 587` which returned

```
PORT       STATE        SERVICE
587/tcp    filtered     submission
```

(normally `nmap virustotal.com` without specifying a port number only returns ports 80 & 443)

I believe 587 is the correct port since it says `submission`. However I am extremely familiar with networks and protocols.

So, any ideas on how to find the proper port I need to "ping" (ask for a connection)? And also in my command, should I use `("virustotal.com", 587)` or `("www.virustotal.com", 587)`?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev thank you for pointing me to an already existing question, I had already seen it and the answers provided but that did not solve my question/problem. Should I ask a new question now, with the same content?

Comment: No, you should edit your question to show how it's different and how that question doesn't apply (because I don't see how). And perhaps make it more focused (you are asking two unrelated things here which is also bad). Then if enough users agree with you, it will get reopened.

Comment: The duplicate question answers that the port here is 443 (and explains why), and I believe this is what you wanted to know.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev imo it is not immediately obvious that "the port here is 443". Just because the endpoint URL starts with `https` doesn't mean that it is indeed using the default port for https, no?

Comment: That's exactly what it means.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I really think that is not the case. 443 is simply the **default** https port. That does not mean that my request **necessarily** goes to that port. I need to make sure to which port it goes, that is why I posted a new question. I also edited it now, to clarify as to how that pre-existing question does not answer mine.

Comment: I don't know what else to say. See for yourself with a sniffer if you don't believe me.

Comment: I don't think it's about me believing you or not. It is about understanding what would be the best way to solve this problem. I did not see "sniffer" mentioned in any answer of the question that you pointed me to. As I mentioned I am not very experienced in this particular field, so could you please elaborate a bit more on what a sniffer is, and which one should I use?