# How to detect if my WiFi is enabled or not with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, connection, urllib

**About question**

- Hello everyone. As I stated as in question title I am wondering "How to detect if my WiFi is enabled or not with Python?".

***What have I tried?***

- I've tried code, that you can find in code sample below, but that code doesn't fit my needs.

  ```
  import urllib.request
    def connect(host='http://google.com'):
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen(host) 
            return True
        except:
            return False
    # test
    if connect():
        print("Connected")
    else:
        print("No internet.")
  ```

**Why does it not fit my needs?**

- It doesn't fit my needs because it will say "No internet" regardless if I am actually connected to network and have WiFi enabled or not. What I need is a way to firstly check if my internet is switched on or not and then if I have internet access or not.

*Any ideas/solutions will come in handy and I think that  the reason why I am not able to solve this is my lack of experience when it comes to Python.*

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62115290/16136190) help?

Comment: Hey @TheAmateurCoder , thanks for the reply! 
I couldn't really understand the code that you've linked me to, so therefore I don't know if that particular code fits my needs or not. 
Anyways, I was able to find what I am looking for by reading answers section from that question, so I am really thankful.