# How many requests can i make to google.com from same IP without getting blocked or something like that?

Tags: python, security, python-requests

I write a program in python and want to check the internetconnection in a loop. i do this with requests modul in python and all works fine but my question is, how many requests are allowed per day, or hour. At the moment i check the connection every 2 seconds so every 2 seconds google gets a request from my ip. Thats make more than 40,000 requests a day, if my software runs 24 hours.
Is this a problem? I cant use proxies because i will not have access or control about the computer or settings of them when my software finally runs by the customer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if an internet connection is present in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913411/test-if-an-internet-connection-is-present-in-python)

Comment: No not really. There are just some other codesnippits to check the connection but no answer about blocking or something like that by to many requests.

Comment: But you only want to check connection right?

Comment: My program is checking but I want to know how many checks (requests) I can make until mit IP will be blocked.

Comment: Why not Ping at random?

Comment: random? You mean a list with some adresses and randomly check? I think its a good idea. Any objections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are rate limits on all google public and internal apis.

However, documentation does not clearly spell out whats the exact rate limit on google.com

If you want to check connectivity, it might be better to use DNS servers such as 1.1.1.1

If you want programmatic access to google.com, you should rather use search API at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: i changed google to 1.1.1.1. I will see what happens if something happens. Thank you.